# Transform an integer to a currency format in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swiftui

How can I convert an Int to display a dollar amount? The sets of numbers I have do not have a decimal point such 1234.45

Therefore, how can I transform the Int `175533000` to `$175,533,000` but not `$175,533,000.00`?

Answer (score 1):

A possible way is the extremely versatile `formatted` API introduced in iOS 15 / macOS 12

```
let value = 175533000
let formatted = value.formatted(.currency(code: "usd")
    .precision(.fractionLength(0))
    .locale(.init(identifier: "en_US")))
print(formatted)
```

Answer (score 1):

#### iOS 13 and all above

You can build what ever you want in SwiftUI just by composing elements together.

For example use `.number` format style and add the `$` sign to the leading

```
HStack(spacing: 0) {
    Text("$")
    TextField("", value: .constant(175533000), format: .number)
}
```

---

#### iOS 15

You can set the fraction length right in the UI:

```
Text(175533000, format: .currency(code: "USD").precision(.fractionLength(0)))
```

<sub>Or just use a separated formatter</sub>